# Is the Chrome Driver Management module downloading the latest version or is it downloading the correct version of my Chrome version?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I know this code allows you to download and use the most recent version of the chrome driver.

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
```

If my version of chrome is an older version, does that code matter? Or does that code download a chrome driver for my version of Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here what official doc says :

> Python module to facilitate downloading and deploying WebDriver
> binaries. The classes in this module can be used to automatically
> search for and download the latest version (or a specific version) of
> a WebDriver binary and then extract it and place it by copying or
> symlinking it to the location where Selenium or other tools should be
> able to find it then.

[Reference link](https://pypi.org/project/webdrivermanager/)

Read more about `chromedriver-autoinstaller`

**Installation**

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

**Usage**

```
Just type import chromedriver_autoinstaller in the module you want to use chromedriver.
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

[Reference Link here](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/)